# Is there a way to encrypt a folder and then only allow certain processes to have access to that folder?

Tags: encryption, filevault

I'm aware of technique for creating encrypted folders using disk utility.

But I believe once it is unlocked and mounted, any process owned as you or root could read that folder.

I'm looking for a way to encrypt a folder and then only allow certain procs access.

Here's a scenario:   Google chrome keeps a directory for cache data, bookmarks, history and the like.

I'd like to create an encrypted folder for this that is only unlocked for chrome.   And keep it encrypted for any backup software or scanners... things that could potentially be running as root that could override an filesystem perms.

Comment: I don't believe that there is a way to do this. I don't know how you'd restrict such a thing. Usually permissions are at a user level -- you either can or you can't. It seems theoretically possible if you could add something to Gatekeeper and then restrict access to it that way, but I'm not aware of any way for an end-user to do that either.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such software available on the net. You can turn on [EFS encryption](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-use-efs-encryption-windows-10) for your private folder, but Windows doesn't give you options to grant access rights for different processes, and EFS only works on NTFS partitions.

There is a third-party software called [Lock My Folders](https://www.top-password.com/guide/encrypt-folders.html), which works the similar way like EFS, and it lets you create a secure folder to transparently encrypt/decrypt the files inside. But it also lacks the feature of restricting process access to the encrypted folder.

Comment: this is an Apple forum

Comment: @marathon  Thanks for your remind! I couldn't also find a similar app on Apple IOS or Mac OS. When the cache data in chrome is encrypted, Chrome should work much slower. For security concern, Chrome lets users to set a master password to encrypt the saved website credentials only.